# Am I integrating SQL Cipher the right way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, sqlcipher

Previously I used the SQLite3 library that comes with Xcode, the code to create a database can be found below:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databases/database.sqlite"]];
    NSLog(@"DB Path: %@", databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

            char *errMsg;

             const char *sql_data = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTableName.....";

            if (sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_data, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK) {

                NSLog(@"Database OK");

                [self setDatabase];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Data Base Fail");
            }

            sqlite3_close(myDatabase);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Database fail");

        }
    }
```

Most recently I had the need to encrypt a database file, and performing a brief search on the internet, I found that some sites recommend using SQL Cipher.

I implemented it in my code in the way that is described in this [link](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/), and the only thing I had to do was stay with that code (which I stated earlier), and use these two commands after **sqlite3_open**:

```
const char* keyTB = [@"MySecretPassword" UTF8String];
sqlite3_key(myDatabase, keyTB, (int)strlen(keyTB));
```

To check if my database was encrypted I open it with a text editor and I saw this:

> øøèDEÆ?>o›$™;⁄iìÚÄ’†í]¥d=ˇÓä\ÊÅº$4áÓÈ?ïÒ[ÅaÚvÁƒ•i%í≈ª¢.£s◊Âc®Øì≈      àÜU—–}Gec‹≥’B∂¡¸¸Æ™√3Ìnú»YÆ"ß
>   ¬?wÚ÷fñoÂ≈ÛÍ¯zÏâ⁄˛Ct°˘ΩfìÙº0ˇﬁ]
>   ‚ŸSw∂â≤≥‘=�H€BN±HÇûß…∑º.náaß¨O¬ˇ¢(B¨‹óµ¬;º‹ÀÒ

Is it really that SQL Cipher encrypted my database (256-bit AES encryption)? or need to do some configuration in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended that you not directly embed the password to the database, however that is not a strict requirement for SQLCipher to work.  Once you have SQLCipher integrated within your application, you do simply just need to key the database with `sqlite3_key` once you open the connection.  To verify the state of an encrypted database, typically one will run `hexdump -C` on the database file itself, the content should appear indecipherable.